# How to run Library and/or Application projects VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm a newbie into this .NET Framework using C#. Some sample codes I downloaded don't run. I know that on my side, I can only run application project and not run any library project. What's the difference between those two? And how do I make library run as well?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't seem to be the kind of question to ask here. Refer to [faq] for more information. BTW, I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Just looked at FAQ and I meant to get some fundamental C# and .NET environment straightened out. Wouldn't VS12 be considered a tool commonly used? I tried to read msdn articles before coming here. But thank you for answering nonetheless.

Comment: You probably should start with an elementary book such as [Head First C#](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-C-Andrew-Stellman/dp/0596514824) or [C# How to Program](http://www.amazon.com/How-Program-Harvey-M-Deitel/dp/0130622214) or use an online C# Course such as [this](http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorial.aspx).

Comment: That is a great link. Code examples followed by descriptions. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library (Class Library in .NET) is some kind of software that is designed to be **reused** and can't be run directly. Usually you use the output of a library project (a **.dll** file) in another library or application. A library **has no *starting point***. So you cannot double click it's file and expect it to start running. It contains *classes*, written by someone else (or yourself), ready to be used in other softwares.

In contrast, an application **Has a *starting point*** (the [`Main`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method), so it can be run directly.

Comment: It is not the most accurate possible answer, but simple and correct.

Answer (score 0):

An application project is a ".exe" file, and a library project is like a ".dll" file. So you can't "run" library directly, instead the library should be referenced by a application project.

Use `Project -> Add Reference` in an application, then select the library project or browse for the .dll file, and then you can use that library in your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing `library project`. There is a `class library`. You can't run a class library only itself. You can add it as a reference to your application project.

**How you can add a class library in your application project?**

- In `Visual Studio`, click `Project`, and then `Add Reference`.
- Click the `Browse` tab and locate the .dll you want to add a reference to.
  **NOTE**: Apparently using Browse is bad form if the DLL you want to use is in the same project. Instead, right-click the Project and then click `Add Reference`, then select the appropriate class from the `Project` tab.
- Ok.

**How you can use it in your application project?**

Add `using [namespace];` to the .cs file where you want to reference your library. So, if the library you want to reference has a namespace called YourLibrary, add the following to the .cs file:

```
using YourLibrary;
```